# Using RegEx for phrase pattern in EntityRuler

Tags: python, spacy

I tried to find `FRT` entity with EntityRuler like this:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = English()
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
patterns = [{"label": "FRT", "pattern": [{'REGEX': "[Aa]ppl[e|es])"}]},
            {"label": "BRN", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "granny"}, {"LOWER": "smith"}]}]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)

doc = nlp(u"Apple is red. Granny Smith apples are green.")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
```

I then got this outcome

```
[('Apple', 'FRT'), ('is', 'FRT'), ('red', 'FRT'), ('.', 'FRT'), ('Granny Smith', 'BRN'), ('apples', 'FRT'), ('is', 'FRT'), ('green', 'FRT'), ('.', 'FRT')]
```

Could you please show me how to fix my code so that I will get this result

```
[('Apple', 'FRT'), ('Granny Smith', 'BRN'), ('apples', 'FRT')]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to fix the whole code by using this `patterns` declaration:

```
patterns = [{"label": "FRT", "pattern": [{"TEXT" : {"REGEX": "[Aa]pples?"}}]},
            {"label": "BRN", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "granny"}, {"LOWER": "smith"}]}]
```

There are two things: 1) the `REGEX` operator itself does not work if you do not define it under the `TEXT`, `LOWER`, etc. [top-level token](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns-attributes) and 2) the regex you are using is corrupt as you are using a character class instead of a grouping construct.

Note that `[e|es]`, being a [*regex character class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), matches `e`, `s` or `|`. So, if you have a `Appl| is red.` string, the result will contain `[('Appl|', 'FRT')`. You need to either use a [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - `(?:es|s)`, or just `es?` that matches an `e` and then an optional `s`.

Also, cf. these scenarios:

- `[{"TEXT" : {"REGEX": "[Aa]pples?"}}]` will find `Apple`, `apple`, `Apples`, `apples`, but will not find `APPLES`
- `[{"LOWER" : {"REGEX": "apples?"}}]` will find `Apple`, `apple`, `Apples`, `apples`, `APPLES`, `aPPleS`, etc. **and** also `stapples` (a misspelling of `staples`)
- `[{"TEXT" : {"REGEX": r"\b[Aa]pples?\b"}}]` will find `Apple`, `apple`, `Apples`, `apples`, but will not find `APPLES`, *nor* `stapples` since `\b` are word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. As always, your explanation is comprehensive, providing additional resources for reference. According to your 3 scenarios, there're no regex expression  that will match only `Apple, apple, Apples, apples, APPLES, aPPleS` but WILL ignore `stapples` (since it's not strictly a fruit of family Rosaceae)?

Comment: @Nemo `[{"TEXT" : {"REGEX": r"\b[Aa]pples?\b"}}]` will NOT match `stapples` due to word boundaries. Please pay special attention to `r` prefix that allows using a single backslash to define regex escapes like `\b`.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. I always find RegEx so confusing. Given your obvious knowledge on the topic, could you please recommend a book/resource that would help me up to speed?

Comment: @Nemo My usual advice is: I can suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/) for beginners, reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at. You should also check [Python `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Wiktor. I wished I have computer science background like you so that I can understand Python `re` doc!

Comment: @Nemo You do not need any computer science degree. The basic things to learn here are: 1) strings and their representation in Python code, 2) basic regex constructs. Play with the patterns at http://regex101.com, follow the `[python] [regex]` tags at SO for a month or two, try answering *good* on-topic questions and you will learn a lot in no time.

Answer (score 4):

You have missed the top-level token attribute which you are trying to match in your regex. Since the top-lever token attribute is missed the REGEX key is ignored and the pattern is interpreted as "any token"

#### Working code

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = English()
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
patterns = [{"label": "FRT", "pattern": [{'TEXT' : {'REGEX': "[Aa]ppl[e|es]"}}]},
            {"label": "BRN", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "granny"}, {"LOWER": "smith"}]}]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)

doc = nlp(u"Apple is red. Granny Smith apples are green.")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
```

Output

`[('Apple', 'FRT'), ('Granny Smith', 'BRN'), ('apples', 'FRT')]`

Infact you can also used bellow pattern for `apple`

`{"label": "FRT", "pattern": [{'LOWER' : {'REGEX': "appl[e|es]"}}]}`

Comment: Thanks for your straight-to-the-point answer, mujjiga. How can I also accept your answer? Can we accept multiple answers?

Comment: @Nemo thanks that it helped. It is ok :) the accepted answer is much comprehensive :)